# How to forward a multipart/form-data POST request in Node to another service

Tags: node.js, post, form-data

I need to send a multipart/form-data POST (xliff file) from the client to my Node.js server, and then capture the data in Node.js and forward that POST to another Java service.

I've used both `multer` and `express-fileupload` to parse the form-data stream and capture a Buffer of the xliff in Node.js and both gave me the file with its content as a buffer just fine.

However, I cannot seem to re-create a FormData object in the Node layer to forward the POST to the Java service.

I continue to get the error message "Connection terminated parsing multipart data" or just no response at all form the Java service.

I've Also attempted to use the `tmp` library to create a temporary file locally to write the buffer and then try to `FormData('file', fs.createReadStream(<path>))`, but that didn't seem to work for me either... though I'm not sure I was doing it correctly.

Using the exact same `doPOST` request directly form the Browser works fine, but once I try to capture the call in the Node layer and then forward the POST to the Java service, it doesn't work for me anymore.

.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

router.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  const { headers, files } = req;

  console.log('--------------- files:', files[0]); // object with buffer, etc.

  const XMLString = files[0].buffer.toString('utf8'); // xml string of the xliff

  const formFile = new FormData();
  formFile.append('file', XMLString);

  console.log('--------------- formFile:', formFile); // FormData object with a key of _streams: [<xml string with boundaries>, [Function: bound ]]

  headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
  const url = 'some/url/to/Java/service'

  doPOST(url, formFile, {}, headers)
    .catch((error) => {
      const { status, data } = error.response;
      res.status(status).send(data);
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't have to convert file buffer to xml string. Instead app directly `files[0]` as buffer array with headers `headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';`

Comment: Passing the buffer of the xliff directly didn't work either for me. I tried that too.

Comment: Found an article doing the kind of same stuff. Have a look https://medium.com/technoetics/handling-file-upload-in-nodejs-7a4bb9f09a27

Comment: Thanks, already read that :)
That article also refers to capturing the form-data in Node, but not how to forward the form-data to a new service, which is my problem

Comment: If `doPost` could accept a stream, you could stream `req` directly to the Java server, no local parsing required.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pseudo code example of the solution I came up with in NodeJS.
I used a similar solution in ApolloGQL, but it applies all the same to ExpressJS.
Hence, my example is in a pattern more akin to ExpressJS.

In the below example shows how to pass a JSON object
as well as passing a file buffer into the FormData before sending it off.

```
const FormData = require('form-data'); // version ^3.0.0

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  const { stringContentOfSomeFile } = body;
  
  // create formData for your request:
  const thisForm = new FormData();

  // passing a JSON object:
  // must declare "contentType: application/json" to avoid 415 status response from some systems:
  const someJson = JSON.stringify({  key: 'value', otherKey: 'otherValue' });
  thisForm.append('data', someJson, { contentType: 'application/json' });
  
  // passing a file buffer:
  const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(stringContentOfSomeFile, 'utf-8');
  thisForm.append('form_field_name_here', fileBuffer, 'file_name_here');

  const response = await axios.post('/path/to/endpoint', thisForm, {
    // must getHeaders() from "formData" to define the boundaries of the appended data:
    headers: { ...thisForm.getHeaders() },
  });

  // do whatever you need with the response:
  res.send(response);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You can directly pass the `buffer` to your form data, but then you also need to specify the `filename` parameter.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

router.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  const { headers, files } = req;
  const { buffer, originalname: filename } = files[0];

  const formFile = new FormData();
  formFile.append('file', buffer, { filename });

  headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
  const url = 'some/url/to/Java/service'

  doPOST(url, formFile, {}, headers)
    .catch((error) => {
      const { status, data } = error.response;
      res.status(status).send(data);
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this response! If I ever got around to working on this issue, I'll try again with your code.

Comment: I was trying to pass an array of files to a Spring WS using FormData and multer memoryStorage. Apparently, all I was missing was the filename in the options. Thank you for pointing that out, I couldn't see it anywhere in the documentation. Although explicitly setting the Content-Type header caused a "FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to figure out how to use a buffer for POST and all I was missing was the `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

For people, who is facing `"FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"` this is what you need to do.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006

This resolved the issue for me. It is not axios specific, we just need to forward the formData headers that is calculated when the request is sent.

For multipart/form-data the boundary is calculated based on file content. The browser does it automagically. But in node.js we need to explicitly forward those. Thanks to `form-data` npm package those are done for you.